# Random shuffled value generator?

Tags: algorithm, random, shuffle

Is there an algorithm that can be used as pseudo random value generator as if the sequence was produced by shuffling ? By that I mean that in a set of k values and k generator calls each value is returned exactly once.

The goal is to have a pseudo random generator that has no duplicates.

The [shuffling algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) is well known and documented. It randomly picks a value in the set of not yet returned values.

This is simple and fine when the list of k values left to pick from may be stored in memory. When the set is big, like for instance the whole set of 32 bit values, it is not feasible and optimal.

**EDIT**: Thank you very much for the answers and comments. I forgot to mention that it should be difficult to predict the sequence of values even when the user managed collect a large set of them.

This is why this question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102073/generating-a-random-non-repeating-sequence-of-all-integers-in-net).

Ciphering the sequence number 0 to 2^32-1 as suggested by @rossum seam to be a promising method.

I have the impression that the use of asymmetric ciphering would be preferable to make it harder to deduce the key from a sequence of values. A solution like [this one](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/55923/4379) could probably do the job. I now need to derive the code to do that. :)

Comment: Seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102073/generating-a-random-non-repeating-sequence-of-all-integers-in-net except it's about the entire 32-bit range

Comment: Linear Congruential generator will work for whole 32bit range, Just use proper values for multiplier and const, and you good to go,

Comment: One method that is so simple and obvious that it would be hard to avoid tripping over it: sample without replacement, discarding draws that have been previously selected. Suppose one wishes to sample from an array `arr` of size `N`. Let `idx` be a collection of indices into `arr` of elements that have been selected. At each step one would (pseudo-) randomly draw indices of `arr` until one is found that is not in `idx`. The data structure chosen for `idx` should of course permit quick lookups (in some languages, a set, for example)...

Comment: ...Drawing a random index that has not been previously selected is a Bernoulli process. If `p` is the probability of "success" the expected number of random draws until a index that has not been  selected previously equals `E = 1/p`. If `M` unique indices have already been selected (the size of `idx`), `p = (N-M)/N`, so `E = N/(N-M)`. One could elect to use this approach if `E` will always be sufficiently close to `1`.

Comment: @MitchWheat this question doesn't answer my question which had the missing information that the sequence should be difficult to predict. This is why a cryptographic method is preferable.

Comment: @Martheen I forgot to mention that the sequence must be difficult to predict. This is why a cryptographic method is preferable. So my question is similar but not a duplicate. I referenced a similar question and its answer I just found in the cryptographic stack exchange.

Answer (score 3):

Use an encryption. Because encryption is one-to-one if you start with a unique number, you will get a unique number out. So, if you encrypt 0, 1, 2, 3, ... with a fixed key you will get a set of unique numbers out. All you have to keep track of is how far you have got in the input sequence, and the key you are using.

For 32 bit numbers, use a 32 bit block cipher. For 64 bit numbers use a 64 bit cipher etc.

For other ranges you could use some form of [Format Preserving Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption), likely cycle walking, for just numbers in a given range.

Comment: That is what II was thinking of by encrypting consecutive numbers. But what encryption algorithm could we use ?

Comment: For 128 bit numbers use AES in ECB mode. For 64 bit numbers use DES in ECB. For 32 bit numbers, you could try Hasty Pudding cipher, if you can find a version for your system, alternatively write your own simple 32 bit [Feistel cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher), though that will not be cryptographically secure should you require that level of security.

Comment: I didn't specify it, but I need that it is difficult to predict the next values. This is why encryption would be a good candidate.

Answer (score 1):

Say we want to shuffle n integers, and n is too big to fit in memory. Choose k s.t. 4n/k fits in memory.

Divide the range 0-(n-1) into k consecutive subranges (0-(n/k-1), n/k to 2n/k-1, ...).

Process these subranges in order.

For each subrange, perform Fisher-Yates as if we were performing it for the full 0-(n-1) range, but when you'd swap with something not in memory, store the swap instead. Each swap is a pair of integers, so at the end of each subrange we might have 3x the size of the subrange in memory. As you store swaps, keep together swaps that are in the same remote subrange (e.g. by using a hash from subrange_id => swap).

After building this hash for a given subrange, in turn load each remote subrange that has at least one swap into memory. Parse your swaps and swap as appropriate. Save the remote subrange back to file once processed.

Then, save the local subrange to file and move on to the next subrange.

Comment: I would prefer a solution that needs less memory.