# 9 character unique random string (for single table)

Tags: c#, .net

I want to generate a 9 digit unique random string. Currently I am using

```
Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-","").Substring(0,9)
```

But I am afraid it would have a collision very soon. Is there any better way for this or would this be OK?

Comment: Unique in what regards? World wide? In your system? What does "for most part" mean?

Comment: Are there several sources that will generate the numbers, or will they be created in the same place?

Comment: @Daniel: Unique in my single table.

Comment: @Fredrik: No, this is used for only generating unique 9 character string for document.

Comment: Like a primary number column starting with 9 digit number ?

Comment: So... Why don't you simple have a running number starting at 000000001?

Comment: @V4Vendetta: Yes but this is not auto increment. It doesn't always has to consist of numbers.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: Because that is not what is required.

Comment: In your question you are asking for a "9 digit unique number". My suggestion fulfills that requirement. If that's not what you want, you should improve your question.

Comment: @Daniel: I've edited the question before you posted the comment :)

Comment: @Jack: If you are ok with a (part of a) GUID, which is a hexadecimal number, why is a running hexadecimal number not sufficient?

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: Yeah that would do. But how do I do that?

Comment: @Jack: Daniel Hilgarth came up with the suggestion, but I suppose he too thought of just storing the next index in a variable and increase it by one every time you add an item.

Comment: @All: Can you please check my answer that I posted and suggest any negative points for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a sub string of a GUID [you are not guaranteed <s>randomness</s> uniqueness  at all](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/06/27/8659071.aspx).

See [my answer to a older SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867758/how-to-generate-a-long-guid/2867832#2867832) to fulfill your randomness requirement. Here is the basic code to do it.

```
public static string CreateRandomString(int length)
{
    length -= 12; //12 digits are the counter
    if (length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length");
    long count = System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
    Byte[] randomBytes = new Byte[length * 3 / 4];
    RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    rng.GetBytes(randomBytes);

    byte[] buf = new byte[8];
    buf[0] = (byte)count;
    buf[1] = (byte)(count >> 8);
    buf[2] = (byte)(count >> 16);
    buf[3] = (byte)(count >> 24);
    buf[4] = (byte)(count >> 32);
    buf[5] = (byte)(count >> 40);
    buf[6] = (byte)(count >> 48);
    buf[7] = (byte)(count >> 56);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(buf) + Convert.ToBase64String(randomBytes);
}
```

it gives you 12 digits of counting to prevent collisions and any additional digits you want of randomness. you can modify the code as you want to make shorter than 12 digit strings.

Comment: As the OP meanwhile confirmed in the comments on the question that a running (hexadecimal) number is sufficient, I think *random* in the question is simply meant to express *arbitrary*, not true randomness in the mathematical sense.

Comment: @OR Mapper: Yeah hexadecimal will do and even truly random will do. In short I didn't want a running number starting from 000000001.

Comment: @Jack: But you said so above: *@O. R. Mapper: Yeah that would do.* Note that `000000001` *is* (also) a hexadecimal number.

Comment: @OR Mapper: I still say that would do and even truly random will do. I don't want my number to be as 000000001. I want that to be abcdefcde.

Comment: @Jack: `abcdefghij` is not a hexadecimal number, but `000000001` is. You are saying that a running hexadecimal number starting at `000000001` will do, but then you also say it won't. Please make up your mind about what you are looking for.

Comment: @O.R Mapper: By mistake I said abcdefghij. I edited the comment before your posted the comment. Please have a look before posting.

Comment: @Jack: Sorry, the edit arrived here only after I had posted. So, what you're saying is that a running number would be sufficient, but you don't want it to contain any numerical digits (i.e. `0` - `9`)?

Comment: @Scott: Can you please check my answer and let me know if any issues with that?

Answer (score 1):

Well, with GUID, it is guaranteed to be globally unique, but only as a whole. You can't assume randomness about a substring of the entire GUID.

Moreover, if you are generating from the same source, there WILL be collisions in substrings because the algorithm uses some of the same variables, for instance the computer's MAC address although I'm not entirely sure about that one. It suffices as an example though.

So if you want to create random strings from substrings of GUIDs, you have to keep track of all the previous GUIDs to make sure there are no collisions. You would get a Las Vegas algorithm.

Comment: Here is the [IETF v1 implementation of the UUID spec](http://www.webdav.org/specs/draft-leach-uuids-guids-01.txt). Section 3.1.2 shows exactly what bits represent what.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to answer my own question since this is the simplest answer that I found. Credits to [Random String Generator Returning Same String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122483/c-sharp-random-string-generator)

```
    private static Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    private static object locker = new object();

    private static string RandomString(int size)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        char ch;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                ch = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * random.NextDouble() + 65)));
            }
            builder.Append(ch);
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * random.NextDouble() + 65))` instead of [`random.Next(65,91)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4)? However this in no way guarantees uniqueness, per your original requirements. you are just relying on luck to not get the same number twice.

Comment: @Scott: Thanks for suggesting. The problem is I tried your method but it either gives 8 digits or more due to Base64. I tried all combinations. I want exact 9 characters. Can you please suggest how do I change your method?