# how to make a plugin secure, so any one if changes something in plugin, it just disables it self and notify us on server?

Tags: php, wordpress

can you please tell me about plugin development,because most of wordpress plugin material referred but no one can define how to make a plugin secure, so any one if changes something in plugin, it just disables it self and notify us on server. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Not gonna happen!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not way to secure your plugin because WP-plugins are open-source and user have fully right to changes.

Answer (score 0):

- **If you encode it with ZendGuard or ionCube**, it can't be modified but will not be GPL friendly so make sure you're OK with that. Plus it'll need a runtime installed on server.
- **If you ship it plain source**, it can be edited and the whole self-verification part can be removed or any obfuscation you do can be reversed.

Scripting languages can't be properly protected, software either.

**[Read this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599837/how-to-generate-and-validate-a-software-license-key)**.