# ConfuserEx not encrypting

Tags: obfuscation, confuserex

i have created a simple webForms(.net framework 4.5, C# , Visual Studio 2015) project to test Obfuscate ConfuserEx
i followed the steps in the post [How to use ConfuserEx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154502/how-to-use-confuserex/48794445)

Tried both GUI and Command line

i used [DotPeak](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)

to test the Obfuscate but no thing is encrypted the encrypted version is the same as the original version same variable names same code

is the previous tutorial still works (the link is 7 years old)
is there any updated Obfuscate

Note i used the latest version [ConfuserEx 1.5.0](https://github.com/mkaring/ConfuserEx/releases)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This post explains the process: https://jonathancrozier.com/blog/how-to-obfuscate-net-assemblies-with-confuserex

The ConfuserEx download is here : https://github.com/mkaring/ConfuserEx/releases

I used Version 1.6 as of today.

In brief, in ConfuserEx.exe:

1. In the [Project] tab, set your Base in & Output out paths.
2. Drag your exe & dlls to the "Drag input modules here" area.
3. In [Settings] tab either [+] to add a level of obfuscation on the
    or do it per individual files you've added.
4. Try different levels of obfuscation by editing the level (highlight
   'true' and click the pen [pen] button).
5. On the [Protect!] tab, press [Protect!]

Steve